# My System.Colors doesnt work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**In my DefaultTheme.xaml File i have only set my colors**

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckboxForegroundColor" 
                 Color="Black"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckboxBackgroundColor" 
                 Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowColorKey}}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckboxBorderbrushColor" 
                 Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowColorKey}}"/>
```

**In my ColorTheme.xaml i have done the same but different colors**

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckboxForegroundColor" 
                 Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckboxBackgroundColor" 
                 Color="#FF2d2d30"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckboxBorderbrushColor" 
                 Color="#FFCC1517"/>
```

**In my App.xaml**

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource CheckboxForegroundColor}" />
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource CheckboxBackgroundColor}" />
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource CheckboxBorderbrushColor}"/>
```

I have tried to follow the colors on this page to get my windows classic look https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpf/2010/11/30/systemcolors-reference/

But it gives my different colors, anybody have an idea what i can do to get my DefaultTheme the windows classic look?

Comment: You don't appear to be using any system colors here, other than `WindowColorKey`, so it's no surprise that you are getting different colors.

Comment: Yes i know, i have tried different systemcolors but it doesnt match with the msdn link. For example my ActiveBorderbrush becomes black not the color as shown in the Msdn link